# Terraform to handle nested loops in tf resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

The below tf module helps to associate floating ip on all 4 interfaces (private_network_count + var.public_network_count + var.management_network_count) on all multiple worker node(instance) based on the worker node counts. The below two resource created for floating ip and association for each instance. How would define loop with one resource of openstack_networking_floatingip_v2 and openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2 dynamically based on worker node count and interface count.

```
Workernode = 2 (instance)
Interface = 4 per worker node(instance)
Floating ip = 8 total ( 4 on each interface on each instance)

 local.tf 
      
      worker_user_data  = <<-EOT
         #!/bin/bash -x
         ${var.joining_command}  --worker --label role=worker
         total_count=$((${var.public_network_count} + ${var.private_network_count} + ${var.management_network_count}))
         counter=1
         while [ $counter -le $(($total_count)) ]
         do
         sudo cat <<EOF > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth$counter
         TYPE=Ethernet
         BOOTPROTO=dhcp
         DEVICE=eth$counter
         ONBOOT=yes
         DEFROUTE=no
         EOF
         sudo ifup eth$counter
         ((counter++))
         done
         sudo cat <<EOF > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1
         10.93.16.0/24 via 10.30.5.1
         EOF
         sudo cat <<EOF > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth3
         10.95.17.0/24 via 10.31.7.1
         EOF
         sudo service network restart
      EOT
    }

    
    worker.tf 
    #---- Provider configuration (OpenStack) ------------------------------------------
terraform {
  required_providers {openstack = {source = "terraform-providers/openstack"} }
  required_version = "0.14.7"
}
provider "openstack" {}


#----- Instance --------------------------------------------------------------------
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "instance" {
  count           = var.worker_count
  depends_on  = [openstack_networking_network_v2.private_network]
  name        = "my_first_instance-${count.index}"
  image_name  = "K8s-baseimage-CentOS-7.8-rancher-2.5.5-1618120048"
  flavor_name = "t3.medium"
  key_pair    = "dsc-keypair-ramesh"
  security_groups = ["default"]
  user_data       = local.worker_user_data
  dynamic "network" {
    for_each = local.network_list
    content {
        name = network.value
            }
        }
}

#----- Advanced networking ---------------------------------------------------------
# Network
resource "openstack_networking_network_v2" "private_network" {
  count = var.private_network_count
  name = "PrivateNetwork-${count.index + 1}-${var.random_id}"
  admin_state_up = "true"
  port_security_enabled = false
}

resource "openstack_networking_network_v2" "public_network" {
  count = var.public_network_count
  name = "PublicNetwork-${count.index + 1}-${var.random_id}"
  admin_state_up = "true"
  port_security_enabled = false
}

resource "openstack_networking_network_v2" "management_network" {
  count = var.management_network_count
  name = "ManagementNetwork-${count.index + 1}-${var.random_id}"
  admin_state_up = "true"
  port_security_enabled = false
}


# Subnet
resource "openstack_networking_subnet_v2" "subnet_1" {
  count      = length(var.public_subnet_cidr)
  cidr       = element(var.public_subnet_cidr, count.index)
  name       = "Public-subnet-${count.index + 1}-${var.random_id}"
  network_id = openstack_networking_network_v2.public_network.*.id[count.index]
  ip_version = 4
}


# Subnet
resource "openstack_networking_subnet_v2" "subnet_2" {
  count      = length(var.private_subnet_cidr)
  cidr       = element(var.private_subnet_cidr, count.index)
  name       = "Private-subnet-${count.index + 1}-${var.random_id}"
  network_id = openstack_networking_network_v2.private_network.*.id[count.index]
  ip_version = 4
}

# Subnet
resource "openstack_networking_subnet_v2" "subnet_3" {
  count      = length(var.management_subnet_cidr)
  cidr       = element(var.management_subnet_cidr, count.index)
  name       = "Management-subnet-${count.index + 1}-${var.random_id}"
  network_id = openstack_networking_network_v2.management_network.*.id[count.index]
  ip_version = 4
}


# Router
resource "openstack_networking_router_v2" "router" {
  count = var.private_network_count + var.public_network_count + var.management_network_count
  name = "router-${count.index}-${var.random_id}"
  external_network_id = "eb240214-a8f8-4418-975f-bbe8f946c2e5"
}

resource "openstack_networking_router_interface_v2" "attach_1" {
  count = var.private_network_count
  router_id = openstack_networking_router_v2.router.*.id[count.index]
  subnet_id = openstack_networking_subnet_v2.subnet_1.*.id[count.index]
}

resource "openstack_networking_router_interface_v2" "attach_2" {
  count = var.public_network_count
  router_id = openstack_networking_router_v2.router.*.id[count.index]
  subnet_id = openstack_networking_subnet_v2.subnet_2.*.id[count.index]
}


resource "openstack_networking_router_interface_v2" "attach_3" {
  count = var.management_network_count
  router_id = openstack_networking_router_v2.router.*.id[count.index]
  subnet_id = openstack_networking_subnet_v2.subnet_3.*.id[count.index]
}

#------- Floating IP ---------------------------------------------------------------

resource "openstack_networking_floatingip_v2" "floatip1" {
#  count = var.worker_count * (var.private_network_count + var.public_network_count + var.management_network_count + 1)
  count = 4
  pool = "External"
}

resource "openstack_networking_floatingip_v2" "floatip2" {
#  count = var.worker_count * (var.private_network_count + var.public_network_count + var.management_network_count + 1)
  count = 4
  pool = "External"
}



resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "floatip1" {
  depends_on  = [openstack_networking_network_v2.private_network]
  count = var.worker_count * (var.private_network_count + var.public_network_count + var.management_network_count + 1)
  floating_ip = openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.floatip1[floor(count.index/var.worker_count)].address
  instance_id =  openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance.0.id
  fixed_ip    = openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance[0].network.*.fixed_ip_v4[floor(count.index/var.worker_count)]

}



resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "floatip2" {
  depends_on  = [openstack_networking_network_v2.private_network]
  count = var.worker_count * (var.private_network_count + var.public_network_count + var.management_network_count + 1)
  floating_ip = openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.floatip2[floor(count.index/var.worker_count)].address
  instance_id =  openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance.1.id
  fixed_ip    = openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance[1].network.*.fixed_ip_v4[floor(count.index/var.worker_count)]

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Also you have to provide values of all your variables and locals, as well as other resources references in the code you provided.

Comment: @Marcin I have added the required info. Please have a look

Comment: Currently Floating ip association done based on interface count for one worker node. but this assoication should happen on all interface counts on more than one worker node count. –                                                                                                           
 variable "worker_count" {
  description = "Worker node instance count"
  default     = 2
}

Comment: @Marcin please find the updated